# Sublime: replace everything between quotes

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I need some help with Regular expression to Search and Replace in Sublime to do the following.

I have HTML-code with links like

```
 href="http://www.example.com/test=123" 
 href="http://www.example.com/test=6546" 
 href="http://www.example.com/test=3214"
```

I want to replace them with empty links:

```
 href="" 
 href="" 
 href=""
```

Please help me to create a Reg. ex. filter to match my case. I guess it would sound like "starts with Quote, following with http:// ....  ends with Quote and has digitals and '=' sign", but I'm not very confident of how to write this in Reg. ex. way.

Comment: Use this regex and then replace the matched chars with an empty string `(?<=href=")http:\/\/[^"]*`

Comment: OR `href="\Khttp:\/\/[^"]*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(?<=href=")[^"]*
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/40